# How to connect to GCP VM instance with password using SSH?

Tags: ssh, google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine

I able to connect to my VM instance in GCP with a SSH key.
I added user with the `sudo useradd -m  -s /bin/bash -G {groups} {new user name}` command, and changed the password with th `passwd {new user name}` command.

I tried to connect to the VM instance with SSH but i received this error: `Permission denied (publickey).`

Please help me.

Comment: It's possible that `sshd` on your cloud instance is configured to prohibit password authentication.

Comment: Here is a recipe to enable SSH password authentication ... https://serverpilot.io/docs/how-to-enable-ssh-password-authentication/

Answer (score 30, accepted):

By default, SSH login using a password (as opposed to keys) is disabled on newly created Linux Compute Engines.  Fortunately, it can be enabled pretty quickly.

Login to the Linux environment and then edit the text file found at:

```
/etc/ssh/sshd_config
```

Look for the line which reads:

```
PasswordAuthentication no
```

and change it to

```
PasswordAuthentication yes
```

Save the file.

Finally, restart SSH using:

1. If your OS is Ubuntu/Debian:

```
sudo service ssh restart
```

2. If your OS is CentOS/RedHat:

```
sudo service sshd restart
```

At this point, you will now be able to login using SSH using a userid/password pair.
To set the password for `$USER`, do:

```sh
sudo passwd $USER
```

References:

- [How to Enable SSH Password Authentication](https://serverpilot.io/docs/how-to-enable-ssh-password-authentication/)
- [Enabling Root Login in GCP VM](https://www.51sec.org/2019/08/03/how-to-enable-root-account-and-enable-username-password-access-in-gcp/)

Comment: Remember. If Google has deactivated by default the login/password authentication it's because it's weaker than SSH keys! Use with caution.