# Google Compute engine WHM root password

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine, whm

I am updating my password using the sudo passwd command in the SSL.
It tells me I have changed the root password but when I try to login I get "The login is invalid."

```
Changing password for user root.
New password: 
Retype new password: 
passwd: all authentication tokens updated successfully.
```

Any ideas as to why this is not updating? (I am currently unable to login to WHM until this password updates).

Comment: Google Cloud Compute Engine VMs have password-based logins disabled. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59533620/how-to-connect-to-gcp-vm-instance-with-password-using-ssh

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out I was using the wrong password originally. When I came to try the correct password it was still telling me I had the wrong details.
By the time I came to reset the password the server had blacklisted my IP (Too many attempts).
The solution was to remove the IP ban and everything was working fine again.

(Huge thanks to the cPanel Support team for helping me find the issue!!)