# What is default user password of GCP compute engine with Debian image?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine

I created an compute engine instance in GCP with Debian GNU/Linux 10 image. I didn't see any option which ask me to configure a password for default user (not root user, the default user name is the username of google account).

After I got the instance then I use the chrome remote desktop to access the instance with GUI. For a while, the screen will be locked which needs me to login with my username (no other option since there is no other user) and password. However, I don't know the password so can't login again.

Any idea what the password of default user is? Or where to configure or check it ?

Thanks.

Comment: Password-based logins are disabled by default for Compute Engine instances. Only SSH key pairs are enabled. @Kolban wrote a good answer on how to enable password logins. https://stackoverflow.com/a/59533871/8016720

Comment: Did the issue get resolved by following @JohnHanley's comment. If yes, can you provide your solution and accept it for the benefit of other community members.

Comment: Thanks John Hanely, that helps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the comment, the solution is enabling the password-based login. The detailed steps are posted in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59533620/how-to-connect-to-gcp-vm-instance-with-password-using-ssh/59533871#59533871)

Answer (score 0):

Actually, you only need to create a pwd to the user shown in your debian GUI screen (the default user name is the username of google account).
To do this, you have to connect to your VM in console mode and use this command:
sudo passwd $USER (where $USER is the user in your debian GUI screen)